# 1980s movie involving a genetically engineered human with a second set of ribs

Tags: story-identification, movie, genetic-engineering

I used to work in a video store back in 1988 and remember a VHS (a magical old format) of a movie that was pretty cool from my perspective. It had a genetically engineered human who was fully grown and had a number of improvements, like faster reflexes and a second set of ribs to act as protection for his lungs and heart.

I remember them throwing a birthday party for him and someone there not knowing he was only one year old, so they were lying to her and made up something to dissuade (her?).

His creator is assassinated and he freaks out when he sees this and, in distress, he just runs outside and keeps going at full speed because of his engineering, but stops when he has an epiphany (in the rain at a truck stop?) or comes to his senses.

He phones the girl(?) or assistant and asks her to come and get him, but because of his speed, he's over a hundred miles away. Maybe over 200 miles. Exact numbers are unknown.

I remember there was an albino cobra or snake that was supposed to have venom 10 times more lethal than that of an ordinary cobra or snake.

Comment: Anit Ad suggested the 1984 TV movie *J.O.E. and the Colonel*, but his/her answer was deleted (not sure why). You can read a plot description [here](http://cybertronicmovies.blogspot.com/2011/03/humanoid-defender.html).

Comment: That seems familiar - his nemesis is another super-soldier named Alpha who has been bred without a personality or emotions. Alpha is killed when he steps on a high voltage cable while fighting our hero.

Comment: Some similar features could be found in "The Flash" https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098798/?ref_=kw_li_tt. Hero was also running at superspeed. May be that serie was inspired by the subject movie)

Answer (score 6):

Ok, lets get back Anit's answer:

It seems to be [**Humanoid defender aka
J.O.E. and the Colonel**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089311/)
([youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hKikNeASa4))

> Scientists create "the perfect soldier" in a lab experiment by
> recombining his molecules. He is then sent out on dangerous but vital
> missions.

Extra ribs:
[image: Wireframe outline in yellow on a black background of a skeleton above the pelvis, arms outstretched. The rib cage is drawn in a lighter colour showing an augmented number of ribs.]

Cobra:
[image: The head and forebody of a cobra, erect with its hood extended.]

Running:
[image: A man in a grey tank top and sweatpants runs toward the viewer on an empty road with black guardrails on both sides.]

Birthday party:
[image: The man in the grey tank top stands with a woman in a white tank top, her hand on his arm, and an older-looking couple in front of a banner reading "Happy Birthday." Another woman on the right is holding a cake with a white candle.]